# .NET generate Zip File using DotNetZip and sent to HTTP Response Stream

Tags: .net, zip, outputstream, dotnetzip

I've got a problem with my following code. I have to use windows 2003 because of the firm. They use this system. This code doesn't work while it works with windows XP.
This code generate a zip file and hen i open it with windows explorer it displays an error : "corrupted file". I use DotNetZip.dll and particulary : Ionic.Zip.
The zip file is sended in HTTP Response Stream.

Can somebody Help me ? Thanks for your answers.

My function :

```
public void Zip()
    {
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"myFile.zip\"");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(Response.OutputStream);

            zipOutputStream.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.Level3;

            string[] filestozip = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\myFolderToZip", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (string fileName in filestozip)
            {
                Stream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName);
                zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(fileName.Replace(dir + "\\", ""));
                int count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                while (count > 0)
                {
                    zipOutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    Response.Flush();
                }
                fs.Close();
            }

            zipOutputStream.Close();
            Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
```

Comment: once i also had this same problem, it was opening on some client but not to others,the problem got shorted out if you save the zip on disk and then make it available for download and remove response.flush()

Comment: I would also remove `Response.Flush();` in that loop. the `Stream.Close` should do that already.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but it doesn't work.
I try to remove Response.Flush() but that's worth.
And I can't save the zip on disk and then make it available for download because that will change all of my client website and my client will never accepted.

Comment: No one can help me ?? Any ideas ?